Coulomb Blockade for a Quantum Dot
I'm working through sections of the textbook, "Many-Body Quantum Theory in Condensed Matter Physics" by Bruus and Flensberg.
I'm specifically interested in transport through quantum dots from reservoirs, but some of the discussion in the section on transport through metallic dots from reservoirs is also relevant. The tunnel rate between two states $\alpha$ and $\beta$ due to tunneling from the left reservoir (L) is given by eqn.(10.9):
$$\Gamma_{\beta\alpha}^{L} = 2\pi\sum_{f_{\beta}i_{\alpha}}|\langle f_{\beta}|H_{TL}|i_{\alpha}\rangle|^{2}W_{i_{\alpha}}\delta(E_{f_{\beta}} - E_{i_{\alpha}})$$
where i is the initial state and f is the final state, with a thermal distribution function $W_{i_\alpha}$. This brings me to my first question:

What is the form of $W_{i_{\alpha}}$? It is not specified. Is this only meant to represent the fact there will be some thermal distribution but this has yet to be determined?

Later in the derivation we reach eqn.(10.16a), specifically just focusing on the reservoir electrons:
$$\sum_{i_{L}}W_{i_{L}}\langle i_{L}|c^{\dagger}_{\nu_{L}}c_{\nu_{L}}| i_{L}\rangle = n_{F}(\epsilon_{\nu_{L}} - \mu_{L})$$
where now the sum is over just the reservoir states, $c^{\dagger}_{\nu_{L}}c_{\nu_{L}}$ is the number operator for the state with energy $\epsilon_{\nu_{L}}$, and $n_{F}$ is the Fermi-Dirac distribution function. This brings me to my next question:

Can this equality be shown analytically? Or do we simply say, the reservoir contains non-interacting electrons and therefore will be distributed thermally according to the Fermi-Dirac distribution? Therefore the sum above finds the occupied state with number operator $c^{\dagger}_{\nu_{L}}c_{\nu_{L}}$ returning 1. So then we have a single term, $W_{\nu_{L}}$, which must be equal to the Fermi-Dirac distribution in the grand canonical ensemble (hence the inclusion of the chemical potential $\mu_{L}$) evaluated at the energy $\epsilon_{\nu_{L}} - \mu_{L}$. Is my understanding correct here?

